# Why can't I assign groupby result back to the original DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Filtering a dataframe with the `apply()` method works as expected, but when I assign the result to a new column, the new column has NaN values (pfa for screenshot).

But if I comment out the `apply()` statement then I can see the value for `violent_crime_count` column. Why?

Data source: https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2015/vwwp-7yr9/data

```
#Load data from CSV 
crimes_2015_today_orig = pd.read_csv('/Users/vishnu/data/chicago_crime_dataset/Crimes_-_2015.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

# create a filter values 
various_drug_off =  ['POSS: CANNABIS 30GMS OR LESS', 'POSS: HEROIN(WHITE)']

crimes_2015_drug_possession = crimes_2015_today_orig.copy()
crimes_2015_drug_possession['drug_possession'] = ''
crimes_2015_drug_possession = crimes_2015_drug_possession[crimes_2015_drug_possession.Description.apply(lambda x : x in various_drug_off)]

crimes_2015_drug_possession['drug_possession'] = crimes_2015_drug_possession.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).count()

# create another column to do count on total count violent crime based on arrest column.
crimes_2015_drug_possession['violent_crime_count'] = ''
crimes_2015_drug_possession['violent_crime_count'] = crimes_2015_drug_possession[crimes_2015_drug_possession.Arrest == True].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).count()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data, Data, data. Where is the data?

Comment: @coldspeed: sorry: i didnot get you. i am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Data taken from https://data.cityofchicago.org/Public-Safety/Crimes-2015/vwwp-7yr9/data</sub>

For the first bit, I'd recommend using `df.isin`, it's much faster:

```
m = crimes_2015_drug_possession.Description.isin(various_drug_off)
m.head(5)
Date
2015-01-01 00:00:00    False
2015-11-24 17:30:00    False
2015-05-19 01:12:00    False
2015-01-01 00:00:00    False
2015-06-24 06:00:00     True
Name: Description, dtype: bool

crimes_2015_drug_possession['drug_possession'] = m
```

---

For the `groupby` operation, observe:

```
crimes_2015_drug_possession[crimes_2015_drug_possession.Arrest == True].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).count().shape
(365, 21)
```

Notice it is not a single column, but you are trying to assign it to a single column. Now, I believe what you wanted was to *count the number of `Arrest`s*:

```
c = crimes_2015_drug_possession.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).Arrest.count()
c.head(5)     
Date
2015-01-01    1092
2015-01-02     671
2015-01-03     648
2015-01-04     513
2015-01-05     520
Freq: D, Name: Arrest, dtype: int64
```

This is still one column, however...

```
c.shape
(365,)

crimes_2015_drug_possession.shape
(263447, 21)
```

Their sizes are unequal. Assignment of unequal sizes will result in assignment by index, and unmatched values are replaced with `NaN`. The result of the groupby operation *cannot* be assigned back to the original.

Comment: The question title is unhelpful since we end up not needing to use `apply()`. (which is what I came here looking for...) In fact this question isn't very reusable or general. And trying to assign the grouped result of a `groupby()` back to its parent df, without at least `ungroup()`, is always meaningless. Any ideas how to update its title to reflect what's really being asked for here?

Comment: @smci Hmm, I've done my best and taken a stab at the title but I fear this is one of those help desk questions that are a bit too localized to be of much use.

Comment: @cs95: Ok but can you please rewrite the first line of question body to state what the OP actually wants to do, rather than just how? It's something about applying to lambda to test membership, then grouping, then a count, then checking if that count equals the `Arrest` column...(??) the explanation doesn't make any sense to anyone unless you load the dataset and run the code. Which makes this question not a reusable resource for anyone else out there :(